# React PropTypes File type

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

How do I check if passed prop is of type File using Proptypes?

using
`PropTypes.instanceOf(File)`
fails with `ReferenceError: File is not defined`

Note:
`new File()` constructor and `typeOf someVar === File` do not throw the mentioned reference error

Comment: `PropTypes.instanceOf(File)` did work for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stemming from this: https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#file-section
So what you could do is checking if the object has a property that is name and that is a string: something like this:

```
const isFile = function(props, propName, componentName) {
  const retVal = typeof props[propName].name == 'string';
  return new Error(
        `Invalid prop ${propFullName} supplied to ${componentName}. It is not a File.`
      );
}
Component.propTypes = {
   onClick: isFile(1) 
}
```